# \sameword in Reledmac within Arabic environment \pstart[\setRL]

Tags: arabic, reledmac

I stumbled upon a problem while using `reledmac` within Arabic environment. The issue is `\sameword` command does not produce the desired effect. I am attaching a MWE with the same example given in the documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[series={A},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale = tunisia]{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\Xnotefontsize[A]{\scriptsize}
\bhookgroupX[A]{\RTL}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\wrapcontentX[A]{\textarabic}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\RTL}
\Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
\Xlinerangeseparator{\null-\null}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother
\firstlinenum{1}\linenumincrement{1} \lineation{page} 
\fnpos{familiar-critical} 
\usepackage{scrextend} 

\XeTeXinputnormalization 1 % for \sameword see reledmac, p. 28

\linenumberstyle{arabic}
\Xnotenumfont{\arabicfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\linenummargin{right}
% Shows which word number in the critical footnote
Lupus \sameword{aut} canis \edtext{\sameword{aut}}{\Afootnote{et}} felix
\pend

\pstart[\setRL]
% does not show the word number in the critical footnote
Lupus \sameword{aut} canis \edtext{\sameword{aut}}{\Afootnote{et}} felix

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is a bug, so please open an issue on github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues